# How to get the body's class attribute?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webview

So I have the WebView loaded with content, and after the

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

method is called, I want to get the body's class name.

How can I do that?

Comment: The HTML is severely broken for starters. Your `head` tag needs closing. Do you really want to put everything in that button element? Also, you're missing a lot of closing tags. Fix the HTML and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you show where you're getting the HTML from?

Comment: Well, the HTML you've linked to is broken, but not fatally. The most important thing I've noticed is that the `body` tag on that page does not have a `className` attribute. So I'm confused why there's such a big difference between the HTML you've linked to, and the HTML you've used in your question.

Comment: Ok, well the problem is that the body tag doesn't have a class attribute.

Comment: I've flagged this questions for closing. I don't mean to offend, but I think this would confuse anyone who came across it looking for answers.

Comment: Probably. Or take out the example HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `class` attribute is actually `className` in the javascript DOM API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

So try this

```
[sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.getAttribute('className')"];
```

Comment: can you tell me more about how the HTML is generated?

Comment: Are you by any chance using some sort of framework that might be loading this HTML as an iFrame?